# Is the location of "A Bridge to the Starry Skies - Hoshizora e Kakaru Hashi" a real place?

Tags: tourism, hoshizora-e-kakaru-hashi

One of the strong points of A Bridge to the Starry Skies - Hoshizora e Kakaru Hashi is the location. The countryside town, with all that pure air, water and greenery really sets the mood and works as a contrast with the Tokyo grown protagonist.

> Shibuya? Is it something to eat? - Ui, ep 7

Is it a real place? Or was it inspired in some real world location? Bonus points for google maps link.

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen Hoshizora e Kakaru Hashi, but I was able to find [a blogpost by somebody who seems to have found the model-location](http://tsurebashi.blog123.fc2.com/blog-entry-85.html) for the countryside part of the show: [Hida-Takayama, Gifu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takayama,_Gifu).

If you want to explore the area, here's [a Street View from just outside the Hida-Ichinomiya station](https://goo.gl/maps/2s83N) (the one whose signboard is shown below), and here's [a Street View from on the red bridge](https://goo.gl/maps/kYrfi) (also shown below).

Here's a couple of the comparison shots from that blogpost:

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

For the dedicated anime pilgrim, [anime-tourism.com](http://anime-tourism.com/cgi-bin/map.cgi) may be of particular interest - it includes a list of locations for quite a few anime, including Hoshizora e Kakaru Hashi. And not only do you get the locations, you get [a map with pins for all the sites you should visit](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?msa=0&mid=z60v_I865QYs.k62viAf4v5Gg)! The pins are, in order:

- Hida-Ichinomiya Station
- Miyanaka School, old building (now demolished)
- Kanzaemon Inn
- Bridge on the way to school
- Bus stop
- Hida-Ichinomiya Minashi shrine
- Liquor store (?)
- Bagpipe Cafe
- Nakabashi / central bridge
- In front of the pickler's